# Access data in NSDictionary using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

[image]

What's the syntax in Swift to access value of `gross` element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would be better pasting the console log as it's easier to understand.

But you should be able to do...

```
var results = //your dictionary

let gross = results["data"]["gross"]
```

Comment: I tried like this...
self.grossAmount.text = results["data"].valueForKey("gross") as String

but the app is crashing...

Comment: @user1382086 ok, but that is not what I put in the answer. Did you try my answer? Also, you are setting text but using a number. Don't do this.

Comment: self.grossAmount.text = results["data"].valueForKey("gross")  - whats the problem with this?

Comment: @user1382086 well the value in the dictionary is a number. You are trying to set it to text. And that's the first thing I spotted.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = results["data"]["gross"]
```